# Extrude along normals not working

Tags: normals, extrude

I can't seem to get the tool to work. I want to have the mesh extrude inwards like in the last picture (taken from a tutorial) . But it just warps and moves in a random direction (second picture). It does work sometimes however in some cases (first picture)

Is there a setting I need to change?

Thanks so much for your time and help!!
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't think that you can extrude vertices and edges along their normals (which would be defined by the faces they are part of), in the video you show he extrudes and scale down right away (S), it's not an extrusion along normals (even if it gives the same result)

Comment: Thanks for your help I managed to get it working! so I selected the edges (2 on keyboard) then pressed extrude (with normals selected) then pressed s (like you said) and it worked!! thanks a million

Answer (score 3):

That's odd.. your tool icon is showing 'Extrude along Normals', but your <kbd>F9</kbd> 'Adjust Last Operation' panel is showing 'Extrude and Move'. If I invoke the tool in 2.92 or 2.93, this is what I see...

[image]

.. 'Extrude Region and Shrink / Fatten', which is what you want. And you're using 2.93.0.

The <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > 'Extrude along Normals' shortcut option is not available for edges, but is for faces,  which, IMO, is inconsistent, and needs fixing.

**TLDR;** Shortcut users would probably <kbd>E</kbd> Extrude, + Right-Click : Drop the extrusion in place, + <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> Shrink / Fatten, as represented in  this illustrated version of the  <kbd>F9</kbd> panel.

Taking @moonboots comment into account, note that edge (vertex) normals are not the same as face normals. If you want a perpendicular extrusion, the last move would be  <kbd>S</kbd> Scale, *not* <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>S</kbd>, along normals. The Pivot would have to be set to scale towards the center of the loop.

Comment: I managed to get it working! so I selected the edges (2 on keyboard) then pressed extrude (with normals selected) then pressed s (like you and moon boots said) and it worked!! thanks a million. its my second day using the program so I just wanted to get a good understanding of the basics. Thanks Robin!!

Comment: If so, please consider to accept the answer @salvador How this site works: https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour